# Issues with Laravel and Vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, single-page-application

I am using Vue and Laravel together as a SPA. I am having an issue where the first time I click a link on the app I see a flash, and after that the page transitions are smooth.

I included a 15-second video demonstrating the issue here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxrP6oa1_a_EcndHWWxBTHgzeEU/view?usp=sharing

The only plugins I am using is vue-router and vuetify.

**Here is my entry file app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import App from './views/app.vue';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

window.Vue = Vue;

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' };
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' };
const Bit = { template: '<div>bit</div>' };
const Bat = { template: '<div>bat</div>' };

const routes = [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
    { path: '/bit', component: Bit },
    { path: '/bat', component: Bat }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App),
    router
});
```

**Here is my main template file app.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-app id="example-2" standalone>
        <v-navigation-drawer persistent dark :mini-variant.sync="mini" v-model="drawer" overflow>
            <v-toolbar flat class="transparent">
                <v-list class="pa-0">
                    <v-list-tile avatar tag="div">
                        <v-list-tile-avatar>
                            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg" />
                        </v-list-tile-avatar>
                        <v-list-tile-content>
                            <v-list-tile-title>John Leider</v-list-tile-title>
                        </v-list-tile-content>
                        <v-list-tile-action>
                            <v-btn icon @click.native.stop="mini = !mini">
                                <v-icon>chevron_left</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-list-tile-action>
                    </v-list-tile>
                </v-list>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-list class="pt-0" dense>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
                <v-list-tile v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" route :to="item.path">
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                        <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-toolbar fixed class="indigo darken-4" dark>
            <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.native.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
            <v-toolbar-title>Toolbar</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>
        <main>
            <v-container fluid>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </v-container>
        </main>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                drawer: true,
                items: [
                    { title: 'Foo', icon: 'dashboard', path: '/foo' },
                    { title: 'Bar', icon: 'question_answer', path: '/bar' },
                    { title: 'Bit', icon: 'home', path: '/bit' },
                    { title: 'Bat', icon: 'settings', path: '/bat' }
                ],
                mini: false,
                right: null
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I also shared the full code here: https://github.com/andrewex/laravel-vue-test

Comment: A question should be self-contained. SO is not a debugging service. Please include a [mcve] in the question description. Also, avoid any irrelevant noise (like thanks or a signature). If you can't put a minimal example in the question itself because the whole project would need to be included, try to reduce the scope of the question to a specific part where you think the problem might come from.

Comment: try to add the mode property to your router config `const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history',
    routes // short for routes: routes
});`

Comment: I tried adding the `mode: 'history`' to the `Vue Router` and does not stop the flash from happening on the first click it only removes the # from the URL.